# wkhtml Authentication required

Tags: html, bash, pdf, authentication, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to convert a html file to pdf with wkhtmltopdf. Everything was fine till the last update of nagios. i got the right username and password but nagios can't find a running session and denies my actions. How can i solve this problem/create a running websession with bash?

My code snippet:

```
user2=$(echo "user" | openssl enc -d -base64)
passwd2=$(echo "$passwd" | openssl enc -d -base64)

wkhtmltopdf --username $user2 --password $passwd2 "$hashsvr" /tmp/hash1.pdf
wkhtmltopdf --username $user2 --password $passwd2 "$hashasr" /tmp/hash2.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Found my error. I forgot to make a dollar sign at the user2 decryption.